# Flutter iOS : Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.3.0)`; `GoogleUtilities (7.2.2)`

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, podfile

I use Flutter with xcode.
I get an error if I do $ flutter run ios
And i get error from my xcode

Podfile content

Error output from Xcode: ↳
`/Users/username/Desktop/Projects/myprojectfolder/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:22:9: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found`

Error in my Terminal: ↳

```
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.3.0)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.2.2)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `Firebase (7.3.0)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `GoogleUtilities (7.2.2)`

[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:
```

Please help me find a solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue back then where some Firebase plugins needs to be installed a few versions lower. More information is discussed on this [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7782). Running `pod deintegrate` then `pod install` on the terminal also works on some, but it may vary depending on your setup.